# Logging to MySQL Table using EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have an application that writes entries into a bespoke 'log' table in my MySQL database, using EF Core; as follows:

```
private void Log(string action, string error = null)
    {
        DateTime logTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
        db.tblLog.Add(new tblLog()
        {
            Timestamp = logTimestamp,
            TimestampMs = (ushort)logTimestamp.Millisecond,
            Action = action,
            Error = error
        });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I have a specific issue where the timestamps stored in the database are not correct; The last line of code is `Log("End");`, but this doesn't always have the last timestamp.  But on top of this I've recently implemented a significantly larger operation that is calling this Log function far more frequently; and I'm starting to get Connection Timeouts and generally poor performance.

I've come to the conclusion that this is not the right way to be doing this.

I've done lot of reading about Logging in .net; but it all talks about logging providers and seems more complex than what I need.

In summary, my question is: What is the best, most efficient way to record simple log entries?

I'm happy if the answer is "find a logging provider", but some advice on how would be appreciated.  Also more reading would be great.

Comment: Enable logging in server : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: If I read that correctly, it will only tell me what the DB is doing; I want a table that logs what the application is doing, e.g. Started; Loading Info; Processing Info; Ended.  Only some of those operations will talk to the database.

Comment: Let the database logging do the stuff causing the performance issues.  You can always add you additional logging in c#.

Comment: Take a look at [ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Logging.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Logging.EntityFrameworkCore) that's a logger provider for EF Core.